# Google Maps API Android - Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I know that there are many topics on StackOverFlow regarding this problem, however none of them could help me.
I am doing a very basic application which I just want to display a MAP.

- I Have imported the google-play-services_lib to my main project.
- I have generated my API Key.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.linkme2night"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.linkme2night.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.linkme2night.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.linkme2night.view.interactwithvenue.InteractWithVenueActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.linkme2night.view.openvenuesmap.OpenVenuesMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBJVHZJr1Q14fcvEHBkAUT1A_ZH4eQlnrI" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Layout XML file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is my code:

```
public class OpenVenuesMapActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_venues_map);
    }
}
```

I am running the application on my Sony XPeria J. I get the following Error generated by Loc Cat:

```
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.linkme2night/com.linkme2night.view.openvenuesmap.OpenVenuesMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1869)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at com.linkme2night.view.openvenuesmap.OpenVenuesMapActivity.onCreate(OpenVenuesMapActivity.java:14)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    ... 11 more
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment : make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    ... 20 more
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment 
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
05-01 18:51:48.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10794):    ... 23 more
```

This is what I get when I create the google-service-lib from existing code, located in my C:/Program Files/eclipse/SDKs/... , and then import it on my project:

[image: error loading lib???]

Does anyone one know What else can I be missing? I am starting to get desperated with this simple thing...

Comment: Did you import the google-play-services_lib project from the android-sdk folder? Also, I think you need to be using the Google API's, not Android 4.2.2...

Comment: @Kaleb The tutorials I've been following all refer to use Android and not Google API as Project Build Target

Comment: You are correct, it had not clicked that if you were using the servcies_lib you were obviously using Maps V2, not V1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your min sdk is 11. You will need to add support library for api versions below 12

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Fragments were introduced in HoneyComb. So for backward compatibality you need add support library

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "
```

Since you din't add support library you got classcastexception

To add support library check the link below

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

> I Have imported the google-play-services_lib to my main project.

Not according to your stack trace. Your stack trace suggests that you manually modified your build path to include the JAR from the Play Services SDK, rather than attaching the Play Services SDK as an Android library project.

Comment: I've edited my question with new information, as well as I posted a new logcat. Could you please give it a look? Thank you very much

Comment: @filipehd copy the library project to your workspace.  Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the workspace to import the library project. Now you can refer the same in your android project

Comment: I've done this already, that's why I edited my Question. Please check if you have time

Comment: @filipehd: The red X means that your reference to the library project is broken for some reason, such as it no longer exists at the specified location.

Comment: @CommonsWare As I import the library, it has a green Verifided Sign. I click Apply, and then OK and when I return it is no longer there, and the Red X is placed. This is quite weird. So but does it mean that the error I get is related to some problem loading the lib?

Comment: @filipehd try copying the library project to a different drive.

Comment: @Raghunandan I've done that. The Library sign now is always as this sign of Verified Green. Still, the log produced by logcat is exactly the same concerning the error :(

Comment: @filipehd If you are targeting an application earlier than API level 12, you can access the same functionality through the SupportMapFragment class. You will also have to include the Support Library. http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html. I see ur min api is 11

Comment: I am targetting API level 17 mate

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="11" your min sdk 11 meaning you wish to support you app on devices that run api  11 to 17

Comment: @Raghunandan That's exactly That! Thank's a lot mate. Maybe you want to make an answer and I will upvote it and mark it as the correct?