# ClassCastException when trying to get Google Play Services Map v2 to display

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been beating me head against a wall with this for a few days now.  I've read just about every post I can on the topic and nothing seems to get me across the finish line.

Trying to build an app using the Google Play Services Map v2 API.

I've got the API key, no problem.

Here are my bits:  MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        if ( status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        }
        else
        {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Relevant manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mcdaniel.mmm4.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mcdaniel.mmm4.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY API KEY" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

I've got past the NoClassDefFound error involving R$styleable, and ClassNotFound of the maps class, but I cannot get past this one.

Regarding the class, I've tried a couple different implementations without luck.  This one seems the most explicit.  No compile warnings.

My target is android-17 with min of android-11.  I've got the library imported (with copy files option), and referenced by my project, and exported too.

Obviously there's something I'm missing.  Please help!

Thanks,
David

Comment: could you post your log?

Comment: you should probably remove your key from up there

Comment: @JRowan No need to be afraid of exposing the key. It is [a] not usable if you don't have their signing key and [b] public value after APK hits the Google Play: nobody can stop you from installing the app, copying to computer, unzipping and seeing (but [a] is still valid).

Comment: ok, i wondered that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast a `MapFragment` (from your XML) to a `SupportMapFragment`.

One possible solution is to change the `MapFragment` in your XML to a `SupportMapFragment` as ankitmakwana suggests in his answer.

A better approach would in my opinion be to set minimal supported API to API12 instead of API11 and use a `MapFragment` instead of a `SupportMapFragment`. Then you don't have to worry about a compatability library.

Setting minimal supported API to API12 instead of API11 shouldn't render (almost) any devices uncompatible with your app, as according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15407738/1274911) posted by one of the biggest Android gurus here in SO, there are basically no devices running API11.

If you chose to go this way, just keep your XML as it is and change the following lines in your code from this:

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
```

to this:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```

It will work then.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!!  I've got a lot further finally!  I changed to min=12, got rid of all references to the support.v4 packages and now I'm not getting those errors above.  But what I am getting is "Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers.  Please add <uses-permission anroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> into AndroidManifest.xml.  But it's already there!  Not sure what's going on now.

Comment: I think there should be `<uses-permission android:name="com.mcdaniel.mmm4.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />` instead of `<uses-permission android:name="com.mcdaniel.mmm4.MAPS_RECEIVE" />`. Please try to edit it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I've got those too, but the error specifically references ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, which I've got too.

Comment: So does it work now? If so, make sure to accept an answer here. (Does not necessarily have to be mine. ;)) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it finally works!  Thanks to all that helped me get there!  I will accept one of the answers, although there was no single one that got me there.. it was a combination of all of your help!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

this may helps you in `xml` change Like  `SupportMapFragment`

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/chk_aerrow_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

for Details  see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034736/display-map-v2-in-popup-window-not-display-in-android/16034955#16034955)

Comment: Simple answer. Zabri and Raghunandan could "fight" less and make their (also mostly correct) answers concise.

Comment: Well that helped, but now I'm back to NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable... so strange.  Thank you ankitmakwana!

Comment: I actually switched back to MapFragment as I really wasn't fond of having to use the support library.  Also switch min=12 as noted below.

Answer (score 0):

```
         My target is android-17 with min of android-11
```

Your min sdk is 11.

Note : **If you wish to run the app on api 11 and lower You will need to add support library as well.**

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Use this

```
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Since you din't add support library you got classcastexception

Also make sure you have followed all the steps from the below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Edit

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

MapFragment for api 12 and higher support fragment for api 11 and lowever

[image]

Comment: API11 **is** Honeycomb. No need for a support library.

Comment: @Zabri i just answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322472/google-maps-api-android-error-inflating-class-fragment/16323629#16323629. Worked for the user. Pls check before downvoting

Comment: @Zabri check the link in the edit for more information. check the last statement in the snap shot attached. you should support your claim before adding a comment.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Removing the downvote now. But please still check the edit I made to my answer.

Comment: @Zabri if he uses support fragment he must add support library.

Comment: Yeah, what I am saying that if he supported min. API12 (which according to CommonsWare's answer from the question that I posted a link to in my answer is the same as supporting min. API11), then there is no need for him to use `SupportMapFragment`. He could, though. But no need.

Comment: Can you support the documentation saying API 12 is required? There were a lot of errors in these docs and this seem like one that is not yet corrected.

Comment: dd you check the snap shot of the edit. check the last line. I don't know if docs contain error. I cannot comment on that

Comment: OK, switched to min=12.  I just want to not eliminate a ton of devices.

Comment: I also removed reference to support FragmentActivity, so now my class extends Activity.  I checked over the two links and followed the 1st 100% to get my initial code, and as I posted above, use the getMap() to actually get the map.  I also now have a LinearLayout surrounding my map fragment in my .xml file.